# jquery animate not working corrently

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

http://fun.townsendwebdd.com/

So this worked when I last touched in on friday.  The problem seems to be with jquery.animate.  I'm using the

```
var w = "+=" + yada;

.animate({left:w}, yada)
```

version.  but instead of adding w to the current position, animate is moving to w.  any ideas.  did they update animate over the weekend (I doubt it) but I am stuck as why this was working and now it isnt

```
var count = 4;
var current = 2;
var timeout = 5000;
var slideTimer;
var speed = 1200;
var slideWidth = 1204;

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#next').click(function(e){
    slide(1);
});

$('#prev').click(function(e){
    slide(-1);
});
});

  function slide(dir){
var w = '+=' + -dir * slideWidth;

$('#slide-holder').animate({left: w}, speed);
   }
```

Comment: I mean I know I could fix this by querying for the current position first.  but I shouldn't have to, and I'm stuck as to why this is happening in the first place

Comment: Slide0 is missing.  I'm not sure if that's a problem?

Comment: function slide(dir){}  it's there

Comment: http://fun.townsendwebdd.com/assets/images/slideshow/slide0.jpg
Error 404

Comment: I see what you are saying.  that shouldn't matter since I never reference it.  I'm actually just moving the #slide-holder container left and right.

well should have never referenced it.  thanks for the catch,  still have the problem though

Comment: I've changed the code now,  now I get the current left, remove the px and parse it.  then I set animate to the new location

Comment: I would like to know why it stopped working the original way, if anyone can tell me